# Javascript AJAX send only part of the data to php file

Tags: php, ajax, post, ini

I use this code to send data to php file:

```
function OnSuccessCall(response) {
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "products.php",
    data: {products:response},
    success: function(data){
        alert('Items added');
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
console.log(response);
```

}

But the problem is that it send only 97 of the records to the php file...in other server I tested it send all 2020 records.

I checked the max_input_vars value - it's big enough - 10000 on the problem server, so the problem must be in some other php configuration, anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: When you are useing console.log for response are you able to see all 2020 records in browser?

Comment: I don't know how big your records are, but could it be `post_max_size`?

Comment: I can see all 2020 records in the firebug, in the browser I cant see all of them, when I use print_r php function it shows only 97 of them. And this is only on the non working server, on working one I see all the records in the browser too

Comment: Its not post_max_size....it is 800M on the non working server and 16M on working server

Comment: Does the problem server have Suhosin enabled? It's often the culprit of inexplicable errors.